# When using .dispose() on RxJava, what happens?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, rx-android

I have been using `.dispose()` to force shutdown my observers in a class in case I go to another view. I am doing this because there are times when I go to a new activity before the subscription is over. However, upon using this I have permanently disabled the observer for the duration of the activity, even when I try and launch the observer again. So to put it formally, does `yourObserverName.dispose()` really destroy future functionality? If so, is there a better way for me to end the observer so that it is reusable if I call it again?

Here is my code:

```
private void setupCoin() {
    Log.d("Video Play", "---Making Coin ---");
    Completable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(displayCoinObserver);
}

// I erase all the observers here. I am able to prevent crashing but If I call the observers again, i cannot create my coin again, thus my observers are no longer working . 

public void disposeAllObservers() {
    Log.d("Video Play", "---Erase Observable---");
    displayCoinObserver.dispose();
    waitForCoinClickObserver.dispose();
}
```

Comment: take a look here https://medium.com/@vanniktech/rxjava-2-disposable-under-the-hood-f842d2373e64

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I understood was that if .disposable() is called, I cannot access the observable anymore. This is a big issue, and I wanted to know how can I cancel my observer without actually destroying it?